# On the notion of Hadamard rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, hadamard-product

Given a matrix $M\in\Bbb F_2^{n\times n}$, define its Hadamard rank $h(M)$ to be the minimum number of rank $\leq2$ matrices in $\Bbb F_2^{n\times n}$ with [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (that is, the entry-wise product $\circ$) equal to $M$. That is, $$h(M)=\min\{k:\exists M_1,\dots,M_k\mid\max_i\mathrm{rk}(M_i)\le 2,\;M_1\circ M_2\circ\dots \circ M_k=M\}.$$

From Arnaud Mortier's argument, $h(M)\leq n$.

> Is there a geometric meaning behind the Hadamard rank $h(M)$?

Comment: Am I correct that the corank of the 3 by 3 identity is 2? Where does this notion come from?

Comment: It's possibly a natural notion but not a natural terminology, as usually corank means something distinct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corank. Even for those not familiar with the classical definition, "co" suggest something such as dual or orthogonal, which is not reflected in your definition. Would you suggest another name?

Comment: I think (and am sure @YCor would agree) that there's no question that there's many ways of being "dual to rank", but a concept that not only is not dual to rank in any obvious way, but (per your question (4)) doesn't even have *any* obvious relation to the rank, surely at least faces an uphill battle to justify the name 'corank'.

Comment: How about 2-rank?

Comment: Maybe Hadamard rank?

Comment: Can you explain why do you find your terminology good?

Comment: You said it yourself - "co" refers to the complement in this case, similarly to codimension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71592/discussion-between---and-ao).

Comment: It is annoying that apparently there used to be some number of questions, maybe 5 or so, and there are a ton of comments and a super-brief answer that refer to the questions by number, without explaining anything; but the questions are deleted. I'm interested in this, but not interested in reading through pages of edit records. I wish that the original 5 questions hadn't been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix full of $1 $'s except on one particular row has rank at most $2$. Hence $1.$ and $2 $. are true.

[Deleted contents regarding 3. as there was a mistake in my spreadsheet - $ A\circ A $ is generically invertible only when $ n\leq 3 $.]       $ $

Comment: Of course this should be a comment but the comments section is being used for other purposes.

Comment: it is ok we can delete comments and move to discussion except yours.

Comment: How does 2 follow?

Comment: Am I mistaken?
If you take $M_i$ to coincide with $M$ on the $i$-th row and full of ones everywhere else, then $M$ is the Hadamard product $M_1\circ\ldots\circ M_n$... right?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier sorry corrected 4. to what I had in mind. However what do you mean by no two columns are linearly dependent and rank $2$?

Comment: @ao. Choose two columns of the required size $n\times 1$,  $C_1$ and $C_2$, linearly independent. Then for the $i$-th column ($i\in \left\lbrace 3\ldots n\right\rbrace$) choose $C_i=C_1+iC_2$.

Comment: Argh, for some reason I thought that one should add the ranks (which would give 2n) - sure you're right!